# SQL Like Command - Dynamic SQL Syntax

Tags: sql

I am having difficulty in understanding how a `LIKE` command should be compiled using dynamic SQL.

```
and camp.description = N''' + convert(nvarchar,@Campus) + N'''
```

This is the query I need converted to a `LIKE` command. Can anyone please assist as I have attempted a few however.

Comment: Replacing the `=` with `like` should do it.

Comment: Strange but works. I don't think I refreshed my SSRS dataset. thanks again

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That's product specific SQL.)